# Error You need to run "nvm install default" al instalar node 8.15 en alpine:3.9 image docker

Tags: docker

Quiero instalar node 8.15 en una imagen docker base alpine:3.9

Este es mi dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

ENV METEOR_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER true
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.15
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm

RUN mkdir $NVM_DIR

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk --no-cache add curl

# Install NVM
RUN curl -o- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh" | bash

# Install NODE
RUN echo "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install $NODE_VERSION && \
    nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && \
    nvm use default" | bash

# Install METEOR
RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION}" | /bin/
```

Pero al intentar ejecutarlo no funciona, sale este error:

> You need to run "nvm install default" to install it before using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estoy seguro si necesitas específicamente la versión 8.15. Pero asumiendo que así sea, el primer problema es usar `alpine`.

[Dice en la documentación de nvm](https://install.meteor.com/)

> Alpine Linux, unlike mainstream/traditional Linux distributions, is
>   based on BusyBox, a very compact (~5MB) Linux distribution. BusyBox
>   (and thus Alpine Linux) uses a different C/C++ stack to most
>   mainstream/traditional Linux distributions - musl.
>
> This makes binary programs built for such mainstream/traditional incompatible with Alpine Linux, thus we cannot simply nvm install X on Alpine Linux and expect the downloaded binary to run correctly - you'll likely see "...does not exist" errors if you try that.

Dicho esto, tienes algunas alternativas.

#### Primero

para poder correr cosas al estilo `curl <url> | bash` tienes que instalar unas cuantas dependencias.

Debajo de `RUN apk --no-cache add curl`

```
 RUN apk add ca-certificates openssl ncurses coreutils \
            python2 make gcc g++ libgcc linux-headers \
            grep util-linux binutils findutils
```

Si haces eso, y luego corres algo como lo que tienes:

```
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash \
&& source  "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
&& nvm install  $NODE_VERSION \
&& nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION \
&& nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION
```

Efectivamente se instala node 8.15.1... pero te reclamará:

```
env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

#### Segundo

para lidiar con lo anterior, puedes usar una imagen de alpine que ya trae node 8 (pero es la 8.16.2 hoy en día)

```
FROM node:8-alpine3.9

...
```

#### Tercero

donde instalas meteor, esto no funcionará:

```
RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION}" | /bin/
```

Tiene que ser, en cambio

```
RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION}" | bash
```

Pero volviendo al inciso **Segundo** si ya tienes una imagen con node 8.16, podrías saltarte el uso de nvm y hacer:

```
FROM node:8-alpine3.9

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache bash curl
RUN apk add ca-certificates openssl ncurses coreutils \
                        python2 make gcc g++ libgcc linux-headers \
                        grep util-linux binutils findutils


ENV METEOR_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER true


# Install METEOR
RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION}" | bash
```

#### Cuarto

Ahora, pensemos que al añadirle todas las dependencias para poder compilar meteor, la liviandad de Alpine se pierde.

```
usando-alpine        latest          e977841adcbe    968MB
node                 8-alpine3.9     9c0651c52baf    66.9MB
```

Si en cambio usaras por ejemplo debian buster en su versión slim, te ahorrarías tanta dependencia:

```
FROM node:8-buster-slim

ENV METEOR_VERSION=1.8.1
ENV METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER true

# Install METEOR
RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION}" | bash
```

**edit** no hace falta instalar bash o curl en esta imagen

El resultado sería:

```
usando-node-buster   latest          fbec649fea7a    836MB
node                 8-buster-slim   5369d1c14056    149MB
```

Si hacemos el ejercicio con la imagen `node:8-slim`, que ocupa debian stretch (es más vieja, pero si vamos a usar node 8 supongo que la obsolescencia da un poco lo mismo)

```
usando-nodeslim      latest          63f47668aec5    827MB
node                 8-slim          d370ba5bae68    139MB
```

**PD:** Hay un dockerfile [disney/meteor-base](https://github.com/disney/meteor-base/blob/master/example/default.dockerfile) para hacer meteor 1.8.1 con node 8, aunque está pensado para correrlo directo en la raíz de un proyecto. Lo malo es que depende de [geoffreybooth/meteor-base](https://github.com/disney/meteor-base/blob/master/src/Dockerfile), y examinándola  se ve que depende  de ubuntu, por lo que estamos hablando de 1.07GB. Básicamente lo que hace es descargar ubuntu, luego meteor y encima le pone node:8-alpine.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Estoy siguiendo el approach # 3 usando FROM node:10-alpine3.9, pero luego de instalar todo y cuando llega al ultimo STEP me lanza este error: Downloading Meteor distribution
tar: write error: No space left on device
The command '/bin/sh -c curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=${METEOR_VERSION}" | bash' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Aplica docker container prune, y docker image ls. Cada intento fallido es 1GB en tu disco

Comment: Gracias, olvide que debo instalar tambien wget. Entonces, ANTES de esta linea RUN apk add --no-cache bash curl Estoy insertando ESTA apk add --no-cache wget. Es la manera correcta, verdad?

Comment: y otra pregunta por fa, es necesario esta linea? RUN apk upgrade ? He visto en algunos ejemplos que SI la ponen y en otros NO. Gracias!

Comment: El upgrade actualizará los paquetes que vienen de base al costo de más peso en tu imagen. No creo que necesites wget. Si está fallando alguna descarga por tema de certificado, podrías probar con `apk update && apk add ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates && apk add openssl curl wget`

Comment: Gracias, en realidad necesito wget ya que esa imagen sera la imagen base para que luego utilizarla para hacer un RUN meteor npm set registry, luego hacer un RUN wget ...., RUN tar - ....., RUN rm ..., RUN meteor npm install, RUN meteor add ...., CMD ["meteor", "npm", "start"] PERO luego de levantar me sale este ERROR: /root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.ani1yi.p0f9s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: No such file or directory

Comment: en alpine viene definida la variable NODE_VERSION, pero no NODE_PATH y puede que por eso meteor se confunda. prueba poniendo `ENV NODE_PATH /usr/local/bin/node` donde defines el entorno